# How to seed the Int.random method call in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm running into a problem where I have a test case failing depending on the random number I'm getting in from the Int.random(:in) method call.

I've looked around and can't find a good way for making the same call but being able to provide your own seed to the generator.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like how are your tests structured, maybe post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator

`SystemRandomNumberGenerator` is automatically seeded. If you want to use your own seeded RNG, you'll have to implement one yourself, conforming to the [RandomNumberGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomnumbergenerator) protocol.

Comment: Thanks, this helped answer my question!

Answer (score -3):

I understand  that you need random integer  from seed integer with SystemRandomNumberGenerator.

Seed items is 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 or other. 
You implement:

```
let seed:[Int] = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
```

then call func random return Int.

```
if seed.count > 0 {
   let number = Utils.random(from: seed)
}
```

with random func:

```
class Utils: NSObject {
    class func random(from:[Int]) -> Int {
        let inline = (0..<from.count)
        var g = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
        let i = Int.random(in: inline, using: &g)
        return from[i]
    }
}
```

Hope, I know you right now!